# Should I further branch off of a new branch or continue developing an additional feature in the same branch?

Tags: git, branching

I have a branch (`dashboard`) which I am developing a new feature on.

To make the example easy to follow, I am developing two separate functions (`function1()` and `function2()`).

They work how I want them to, but I now want to attempt to merge `function1()` and `function2()` together to make `new_function()` because I think it will streamline the process in future.

Note that this wasn't in my original plan - the original plan was to develop `function1()` and `function2()`, which is why I created the `dashboard` branch; however, I think that creating `new_function()` might be an even better solution but I don't want to jeopardise anything I have already done.

Let me mention that I absolutely get the whole point of version control - being able to roll back, etc. - and that I could just roll back any changes that I am unhappy with; however, as I currently have `function1()` and `function2()` working well, I think creating a new branch might be easier to manage and will also make everything simpler overall.  If `new_function()` is a success, I can merge it back into my `master` branch; if not, I can delete the new branch and return to `dashboard`, with the intention of merging that back into my `master` branch once complete.

I'm sure that an aspect of personal preference will play a role here, but what is (typically) best practice in such a scenario?

Comment: Sounds to me like you've got it all figured out. Seems like a good plan

Comment: Is a downvote really necessary here?  It's a perfectly valid question and a helpful comment would have been much more useful.

Comment: Really?  Another downvote?  I don't understand why people can't just raise their issues with the question via comments instead of downvoting - it would be much more constructive that way.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a new branch from your dashboard branch is the way I would do it. I sometimes prefix these with "R&D".

Remember that a branch is just a label on a commit. Keeping dashboard where it is makes it easy to go back to that commit where you know everything was working.